# How to check if row is empty and hide a div with PHP and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, show-hide

I know it's bad putting JavaScript inside PHP, but I'm rendering HTML with PHP and i want to check if row is empty and hide each of those HTML elements in a class. I know about Ajax, I just want this in PHP.

PHP:

```
if ($row['image1'] != ''){
echo   '<script>
        $(".image1Class").each(function() {
        $(this).show();
        });
    </script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't clearly understand what you want to do, but instead of

```
if ($row['image1'] != '')
```

you can use

```
if(!empty($row['image1']))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help your**

```
 $(".image1Class").each(function () { 
     if ($(this).attr("src") == "" ) 
     {
       $(this).css("display","none");  
      }
     });
```

Comment: You are suppose to evaluate the presence of a value from table with PHP first before performing operations, i want this to be done before anything is rendered to the browser.

Comment: So your condition should be done with PHP, to get the table state from sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(
    function (){
      <?php if ($row['image1'] != ''): ?>
        $(".image1Class").show();
      <?php else: ?>
        $(".image1Class").hide();
      <?php endif; ?>
    }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: You are hiding everything in that class, i want to hide only empty div, that's why i used $(this).